# Where is Ubuntu 20.04 default network configuration?

Tags: networking, xubuntu

I recently installed Xubuntu 20.04.  I figure that it's using the same network configuration as Ubuntu of the same version, so I'm asking here.
Network works fine.  However, I'd like to find where the default network configuration is precisely.  I've read about netplan and Network Manager and the config files for them should be in /etc/ although I did a grep on all files in /etc/ and the IP address is very seemingly nowhere to be found.  I can follow any tutorial on using netplan or NM or I can even switch to the ol' ifupdown but I don't see the point of changing anything if I can't figure out how the current, default, out-of-the-box so to say, working network config works.  Help would be appreciated - thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server & Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop differ in networking, though Xubuntu 20.04 LTS is the same as Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop (both using *nm*).  You didn't clarify if you meant Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop or Server.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't put SOLVED in the question title in this question answer site. You should click the gray check ✔️ next to the correct answer and turn it green ✅. This marks the question as solved and will help others.

Answer (score 4):

Your established connections can be found in the following directory:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
```

Here, you will find an individual file for each known connection.

Unless your IP is static, the IP will not be listed in the file as the IP will be assigned dynamically by DHCP through your router. Also, you need root permission to read these files so a simple grep may not suffice unless you use `sudo grep`.

When you set up everything through NetworkManager using the GUI, these files will create automatically. However, you can edit these files manually but you will need to restart NetworkManager after making any changes using `sudo systemctl restart network-manager`. You can also set up a connection using `nmcli` but that's another story.

There are more parts to your network like DNS that are setup with other files in other places depending on what you use for DNS but again, that's another topic.

Comment: Remember, on Ubuntu, files and directories are case sensitive so `ls /etc | grep "network"` will not return for the `NetworkManager` directory unless you use `ls /etc | grep -i "network"` or `ls /etc | grep "Network"`

Comment: Or the lazy way: `ls /etc | grep etwork` ;-)

Comment: "However, you can edit these files manually" Are these text files for you? For me these are binary files (with extension `*.nmconnection`), I can't even view their content in my regular text editor.

Comment: @Levente Yes, these are text files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks !  I appreciate the responses.  I'm actually a bit ashamed as to what the problem was, so let me provide a somewhat ironic answer to myself :

Next time try to pay attention !  You did a grep over the contents of /etc/ using emacs' find-grep and a search criteria of '192' hoping you'd see the IP address of the working network interface and where it's actually configured but you saw nothing related.  That should have told you something.  That the address configuration is not within the OS.  And what does that mean ?  Yes, it gets the address via DHCP, the DHCP service of your router !  So next time, try to pay more attention to what you are actually observing !

:)  Thanks again folks, it's nice to see that there's a community response !

And I'll try to do better next time around, before asking a question !

Cheers.